# Argparse SystemExit: 2

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, computer-vision, argparse

My code...

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import sys
import cv2 as cv

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,   help = "path to trained activity recognition 
model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--classes", required=True, help = "path to class label file")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", type = str, default = "", help = "optional file to video file")

args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

I'm following [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/11/25/human-activity-recognition-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/) tutorial. Here getting the error is

**usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] -m MODEL -c CLASSES [-i INPUT]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -m/--model, -c/--classes**

**An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.**

**SystemExit: 2**

Comment: You can't use `argparse` within a `jupyter-notebook`.   The commandline values you give when starting the server are intended for the server itself, not your notebook.  This code is designed to be run as a 'plain' python script (from shell).

Answer (score 1):

For argparse, you need to supply the arguments on the command line. For example, you can save the script as `script.py` and run as `python script.py -m somemodel -c someclass` to give the required arguments. If you are using an IDE such as Spyder, it should have an option to supply command line arguments somewhere.